# Comment system query to pull parent + x no. of child comments

Tags: mysql

I'm making a comment system.  It's not completely nested, each parent comment can have replies but replies can't have replies.  My question is what query could I use to extract x number of parents and the first y number of replies for each one.  So for example I would pull out and display 10 parent comments and just the first 2 replies to each one.  Is this possible with 1 query?

My CommentTable is as follows:
CommentId
ParentId
Content

ParentId is 0 for parent comments, replies have a ParentId equal to the CommentId they are a reply to.

Answer (score 0):

I am just looking at a similar issue.

I think you are talking about the Adjacent Lists model described here:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

So you could return the first 2 comments using a 2 level self join.